# Is there a list of pre-defined PCI capability IDs?

Tags: pci

During reading various documents I found that:

1. The PCI Power Management capability ID is **0x1**
2. The MSI Capability ID is **0x5**

Is there a list of pre-defined/standardized PCI capability IDs?

Comment: There seems to be a list on page 22-23 of this document: https://pcisig.com/sites/default/files/files/PCI_Code-ID_r_1_11__v24_Jan_2019.pdf

Comment: Thanks, that's what I looked for!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [PCI Code and ID Assignment Specification](https://%20https://pcisig.com/sites/default/files/files/PCI_Code-ID_r_1_11__v24_Jan_2019.pdf).

It contains the ID assigment for both PCI Capabilities and PCIe Extended Capabilities.

(Just noticed that it is the same link in the comment by @RuudHelderman.)